How good is Quicken Spell as a feat?
I wonder if Quickened Spell is overrated because I see people saying it is essential as a key component of high-level action economy.
But as it is actually a swift action (or a free action that can only be used in your own turn), I don't feel it is as useful as it seems to be. The only thing it actually allows you to do is letting you cast 2 spells in the same round (and you won't want to use the quickened one as a readied action, since that requires a standard action), while your quickened spell has to cost a much higher spell slot (which means it would likely be a low-level buff or control spell).
I feel like having a metamagic rod of quicken would be much better than taking it as a feat, and I can't think of a use case that can make this feat particularly useful. Wondering if my understanding is wrong or if I overlooked anything.


The only thing it actually allows you to do is letting you cast 2 spells in the same round

Oh, just that, huh? Just getting to do the most powerful possible thing you can do twice in a turn?
Anyway, at high levels of optimization, Quicken Spell does not cost 4 spell levels. It’s not unheard of for a high-level build to spend four or five feats making it cheaper so they can apply it to more spells, more often. That’s a high cost, but the value is so astronomical that a lot of builds find it worthwhile.
And that’s to say nothing of incantatrix.
There’s also just certain spells that are very amenable to metamagic. Enervation is a classic for that, for instance. And that’s a 4th-level spell—even if you wind up casting just quickened enervation from an 8th-level spell slot, that’s still a really effective thing to add onto your turn that’s already dedicating a standard action to a metamagic’d enervation. And that’s basically the no-optimization version of that build, just taking a bunch of metamagic feats.
As for a metamagic rod of quicken spell, it’s definitely also good. It’s also very expensive, and you may well want to use that effect a lot—quite possibly more than 3 times per day. Maybe you can convince a DM an at-will version should cost just 1⅔× the cost, as the guidelines suggest. But probably not. Just taking Quicken Spell and reducing its cost is a much more reliable (in the sense of being allowed at more tables) way of achieving that result.

The second paragraph needs to be in bold

With additional feat or class investment, the higher spell slot cost can drop dramatically. Sure, four slot levels higher is hard to justify even with the action economy advantages, but with abilities that reduce the incremental slot level cost, it can be very useful. Sure, it costs feats, but being able to cast a pair of powerful spells per round, with only a 1-2 level cost, rather than 4, is a major force multiplier.

I did see it could drop dramatically, but that usually means the build would go all-out for metamagic (like investing 10 levels into a single PrC or take several extra feats to support the build). I guess it would be costly if a spellcaster is aiming to do something else as well, but still a worthwhile option.

Your analysis makes a mistake that I see all too frequently when it comes to analyzing specific mechanics in TTRPGs: You’re looking at the mechanic in isolation, not in the context of the whole game. It’s extremely important to remember that no mechanic functions in total isolation.¹
If you assume that a spell is roughly equivalent to a typical attack by a martial character of the same level as a caster who can cast that spell and that there’s no way to reduce the metamagic cost, then Quicken Spell does indeed look pretty mediocre.
But neither of those assumptions is true.
Time Stop is a trivial counterexample to the assumption that spells are equivalent in relative power to martial attacks (especially since it needs no expensive material component and doesn’t cost XP), though it’s too high of a level of our purposes if we assume the other assumption holds. Looking more clearly at lower levels that would be more likely to have Quicken Spell used on them, Black Tentacles and Cloudkill are both relatively easy examples of spells that are far stronger than a standard action from a martial character of equivalent level in a nontrivial number of situations (and the two combined showcase an easy combo that is only possible to execute in one round if you use Quicken Spell).
And as far as reducing the metamagic cost, that’s not as straightforwards, but it is doable. There are at least six feats and three prestige classes that allow for this in some way or another. And if you can reduce the cost to even just a +2, Quicken Spell easily becomes far and away the strongest metamagic feat in the game. And the impact is so striking that a lot of the best high-level builds involve spending 4-5 feats on just reducing the cost of Quicken Spell so that it can be used more frequently on more spells.

1: In the specific case of older systems like D&D 3.5e, it’s also important to remember that people have been trying to optimize and break the system for years (remember, D&D 3.5e is over 20 years old now), and indirectly cross-checking each others’ work as they do so, so it’s relatively unlikely that everybody involved in the system is wrong about something being very strong (or very weak). This is not to say you shouldn’t be skeptical at times, but if your analysis disagrees with the majority on such things, it’s far more likely that you’re missing something, not that everybody else is wrong.
